Facing Problem opening ubuntu on ssd but harddisk problem
I have both an SSD and a hard disk in my laptop. But today, after I installed Ubuntu 24.04 on the SSD instead of Windows, Ubuntu doesn't open when the hard disk is connected; instead, a Pop!_OS popup appears. However, when I remove the hard disk and start the laptop, Ubuntu opens correctly. I used to have Pop!_OS installed on the hard disk. Later, I got a 256GB SSD and installed Ubuntu on it, and now I'm using the hard disk as secondary storage. The hard disk only has some photos and videos, nothing else. So, does this mean I can't use both the SSD and hard disk together on Ubuntu? If I can, please provide a solution.

With both drives installed, enter your computer's setup and select to boot from SSD, save the setup changes and try to enter Ubuntu.

Is one install UEFI and other BIOS? And then is system set to boot in wrong mode. Most systems are UEFI. And how you boot install media is how it installs. Installs should be UEFI to gpt partitioned drives. Then UEFI/BIOS needs to be set to default boot in UEFI mode.
